# XSD - Validating an XML instance with multiple namespaces

Tags: xsd

What does it mean if we say that, using XSD, we can validate XML documents that contain multiple namespaces. Does this make sense?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. There are a lot of reasons why an XML document may have multiple namespaces, but the most common is that it contains structures that are defined by different organizations. The typical way to do this is to use the `xs:import` directive to combine independent schema documents into one master schema.

For more information, see http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#import

Comment: I see. So if in an XML instance, we are using different namespaces for different vocabularies, we will have several imports for the associated schemas so that the XML instance can be correctly validated? Is this correct? Thanks very much for your reply